# Does soaking apples in baking soda for 15 minutes remove pesticides?

Tags: apples

I read this on the internet. How can this be true when apples are waxed?  Wouldn't the pesticide be *under* the wax?

If anybody has any ideas how to get rid of *both* at the same time without using boiling water which will trash the pot you use with baked in wax I would sure like to know.

Comment: You could probably ask this on the Skeptics site, if you include a source. If the source is notable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some [truth](https://globalnews.ca/news/3826356/washing-apples-baking-soda/) (and [this](https://www.cooksillustrated.com/articles/2075-can-baking-soda-remove-pesticides-from-produce) ) that baking soda helps removing **some** pesticides.

You can wash your fruits under running warm water to remove most of the wax and some pesticides and after that, use baking soda.

If all fails, you can remove the skin of the apples.

Comment: The wax is not so bad as I learned from another excellent post answered just recently. And yes If pesticides are a concern the best would probably to peal them instead of learning the technical details of pesticides. Thank you :-)